# When my InputFilter source comes in as spannable, the source does not remove the characters I filter out

Tags: android, kotlin

I am filtering most characters and numbers out in this use case. When I type several 'filtered' characters, let's say 555, the `source` of each following filter event still has those 5's in it, even though they have been filtered out. This means that after typing 555, and having nothing appear in the EditText, I have to backspace 3 times before I actually start backspacing what is in the EditText. Not only that, but my 'invalid input' toast fires on every backspace, because my `source` still has the 5's in it.

So, if I type abc123abc, my field shows abcabc, but logging my `source` shows abc123abc and I throw invalid toasts all over the place.

The superclass for the filter has nothing except a protected method to show the toast, and is used on the filters that work, as well.

InputFilter

```
class TextInputFilter constructor(
    private val letters: Boolean,
    private val numbers: Boolean,
    private val whitespace: Boolean,
    private val extraCharacters: Array<Char>,
    context: Context?
) : ToastInputFilter(context) {

    override fun filter(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
        var valid = true
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        source.forEach { c ->
            if (c.isValid()) {
                builder.append(c)
            } else {
                valid = false
            }
        }
        return if (valid) {
            null
        } else {
            showInputToast(R.string.textInputInvalid)
            if (source is Spanned) {
                val spannable = SpannableString(builder)
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom(source, start, builder.length, null, spannable, 0)
                spannable
            } else {
                builder
            }
        }
    }

    private fun Char.isValid(): Boolean {
        return when {
            isLetter() -> letters
            isDigit() -> numbers
            isWhitespace() -> whitespace
            else -> this in extraCharacters
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiation with args

```
titleEditText.filters = arrayOf(
                TextInputFilter(letters = true, numbers = false, whitespace = true, extraCharacters = chars, context = context)
            )
```

The extra chars that I'm allowing

```
    chars = safeGetString(R.string.alphaExtraChars).toCharArray().toTypedArray()
```

```
    <string name="alphaExtraChars">\'.-</string>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and I have other filters that work fine on number input, because the source does not come in as `Spannable`, and only deals with the new piece of input, not the entire field.

Edit after using start|end arguments, this happens:

```
A -> Log: A | Display: A
b -> Log: Ab | Display: Ab
c -> Log: Abc | Display: Abc
1 -> Log: Abc1 | Display: Abc + TOAST
2 -> Log: Abc12 | Display: Abc + TOAST
3 -> Log: Abc123 | Display: Abc + TOAST
Backspace -> Log: Ab | Display: Ab
```

Good.
But, when I keep typing valid characters after invalid characters:

```
A -> Log: A | Display: A
1 -> Log: A1 | Display: A + TOAST
a -> Log: A1a | Display: Aa + TOAST
1 -> Log: A1a1 | Display: Aa + TOAST
a -> Log: A1a1a | Display: Aaa + TOAST
Backspace -> Log: A1a1 | Display: Aa + TOAST
Backspace -> Log: A | Display: A
```

Comment: `source.forEach` looks like it could be your issue. You're ignoring `start` and `end`. I don't know why `source` isn't simply the new characters and `start` and `end` are necessary, but there must be some optimization going on behind the curtain, so you should only put characters of `source` that are between those indices into your builder.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That's a good point, but here's a fun fact: If I remove the Toast, everything works perfectly. And, if I wait between key presses until the toast finishes, it ALSO works. If I move the toast outside of the same scope block as what else is there, the same things happen, so it doesn't have anything to do with the return block somehow getting delayed. I think that while it is running the Toast, the source stacks up and gets wonky. So... I guess no toast from inside the filter.

Comment: I'm going to retry with the toast in a separate thread in a callback to the UI context owner, instead of doing it here. It seems to be pretty directly related to running it inside of the filter. Will update when I try that.

Comment: In your edit, it looks like it's behaving correctly to me in your last set of logs. What am I missing? Is it that you don't want the toast to display when the user presses backspace?

Comment: When pressing backspace, I would expect `start == end` so you shouldn't reach your else block, assuming you are never looking at a character outside that range.

Comment: The toast is firing when the user types 'a', because a 1 is still stored in source, and the entire source (not just the 'a') is being passed into the filter

Comment: But if you're only looking at characters between start and end, you won't reach your else block because you won't be looking at the `1` character again.

Comment: I think that's the misunderstanding here: start and end are 0 and last. Because it came in a spannable, the filter is attempting to replace the ENTIRE dest with the ENTIRE source, because it's picking the whole thing up in a span. In my numeric input fields, this is not the case and what you're saying is true.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this to concisely take the source delimiters into account:

```
override fun filter(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
    val builder = StringBuilder()
    for (c in source.subSequence(start, end) {
        if (c.isValid()) builder.append(c)
    }
    return if (builder.length == end - start) {
        null
    } else {
        showInputToast(R.string.textInputInvalid)
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edits to the original question - still broken.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the characters that I am filtering out are being persisted by one of the InputFilter/EditText/Spannable/Editable and being returned in the the source. Because it's a text field, when we receive a Spannable, it attempts to replace the entire string, not just one character. This is due to how the InputFilter deals with Spannable vs not Spannable, and why it receives one vs the other.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider simplifying the whole thing to reject any incoming block of text if it contains *any* invalid characters. Presumably, you will get either one new character at a time, or the user is pasting a block of text. Do you really want to filter pieces of a block of text that contains invalid characters? In many cases, this would be unexpected behavior.

So if it's acceptable behavior to do this, your filter simplifies down to:

```
override fun filter(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
    for (i in start until end) {
        if (!source.charAt(i).isValid()) {
            showInputToast(R.string.textInputInvalid)
            return ""
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't address the problem that it is attempting to replace the ENTIRE field with the ENTIRE entry - right? So, imagine someone types 20 valid characters and then bumps a number. It would wipe the whole field. Because it uses the entire field as the 'source' intended to replace the entire 'dest', even one character entry would wipe the entire field. It still boils down to this horrible 'is the source Spannable or not' (This was an option I've tested already)

Comment: Is it? That would violate the javadoc for the method. If you look at the source code of InputFilter.LengthFilter, they use `""` to reject changes, and they don't consider whether Source is a Spanned at all.

Comment: It is for me, but I'll keep exploring and see if I can find what's up.