# When the first letter isn't accepted by an input filter, no entry will be accepted

Tags: android, kotlin

This is similar, but a somewhat different problem than the question I asked here: [When my InputFilter source comes in as spannable, the source does not remove the characters I filter out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826797/when-my-inputfilter-source-comes-in-as-spannable-the-source-does-not-remove-the?noredirect=1#comment103958390_58826797)

In my example, I'm making an input filter to validate Canadian zip codes.

I have an abstract here:

```
abstract class MyInputFilter : InputFilter {

protected abstract fun String.isValid(): Boolean

private fun getFinalResultOfChange(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence {
    return dest.replaceRange(dstart, dend, source.subSequence(start, end))
}

private fun getNoChangeResult(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence {
    val initialSubSequence = dest.subSequence(dstart, dend)
    return try {
        if (source is Spanned) {
            val spannable = SpannableString(initialSubSequence)
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom(source, start, end, null, spannable, 0)
            spannable
        } else {
            initialSubSequence
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        initialSubSequence
    }
}

override fun filter(source: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned?, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
    if (source == null || dest == null) {
        return null
    }

    val input = getFinalResultOfChange(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend).toString()

    return if (input.isValid()) {
        null // Allow the edit to proceed unchanged.
    } else {
        getNoChangeResult(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend)
    }
}
```

}

which I inherit and override isValid for all of my input filters. This filter is... weird, but came about based on the question linked above, and somewhat solved the problem I had.

This is naive due to my intent to be deliberate, but here is the CAN filter:

```
    private val patterns = listOf(
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy]$",
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9]$",
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9][A-Za-z]$",
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]$",
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z]$",
        "^(?!.*[DFIOQUdfioqu])[A-VXYa-vxy][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z][0-9]$"
    )

    override fun String.isValid(): Boolean {
        return when (length) {
            0 -> true
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 -> this.matches(Regex(patterns[length - 1]))
            else -> false
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a new problem. If the very first character entered is an invalid letter, the keyboard keeps loading the characters into a 'word' and trying to resubmit them. So, if I type

```
D
```

nothing gets entered, correctly. But, if I type

```
DA
```

still nothing is entered, and my phone is trying to 'auto suggest' the word "da". Unless I either click the suggested word or backspace to empty, the field WILL not accept any input of any kind, but the keyboard will continue to 'queue' a word with all of the letters I've typed. If I input a bad character in ANY OTHER position, as long as the first character has been accepted, it works. The phone does not start 'queueing' a word into the keyboard, and I can immediately enter the correct character.

Also of importance: Numbers do not cause the problem. The keyboard does not try to start 'building' a word from a number, so if I type

```
1A
```

then "A" is entered into the field with no problems.

I can't find nearly anyone else having these problems with input filters and spannable vs not spannable CharSequence input, but the keyboard is building a word and trying to submit the whole thing in a way that I don't understand. I've tried it on the GBoard on a OnePlus 6T, as well as the default samsung keyboard of a Samsung Tab E, so it doesn't feel like an individual keyboard bug.